# Solr - Unique Key Exception

Tags: solr, solrj

Is there any way Solr can throw exception back, either in the status or exception message somehow, for an update request that having an existing unique key. Right now, Solr just sends back a good update message with status 0 while its not adding the document. I need an ability to tell from the client side that if a document was not added because of the duplicate unique key issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If a document with the unique id exists, solr just updates the doc.  It is by design and as far as i know, there is no way to change it.

You can solr query before you update/add a doc, so that you are not adding it again...  but that is not really transactional (solr is not a database).It'd work if you are the only one updating solar and the changes are serialized etc.

If you have this stringent requirement on not adding existing ids, you could use an intermediary database, load it and reindex solr from that..?